# Infinitesimal geodesic motion directly from the metric?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, variational-principle, geodesics

**How can I see---directly from the Schwarzschild metric---that initially stationary (w.r.t. Schwarzschild coordinates) inertial test clocks will begin to fall toward e.g. the Earth (i.e. far outside the Schwarzschild radius)?**

Suppose I take the Schwarzschild line element
$$
(c\,\mathrm{d}\tau)^2=\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)(c\,\mathrm{d}t)^2-\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1}\mathrm{d}r^2,
$$
where I've neglected angular contributions, since I only want to consider radial motion. Further suppose I have an inertial test clock satisfying $\left.r\right|_{t=0}\equiv r_0>r_s$ (i.e. initially outside the Schwarzschild radius), $\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}=0$ (i.e. initially at rest in Schwarzschild coordinates), and $t=0\iff\tau=0$ (i.e. clocks begin synchronized). I can see fairly readily that the geodesic equation will imply a negative coordinate acceleration $\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^2r}{\mathrm{d}\tau^2}\right|_{
\tau=0}<0$, and hence the test clock will begin falling toward e.g. the Earth.

But is there a way to perhaps see this same result more directly from the metric, i.e. without resorting to the geodesic equation? I'm imagining something akin to taking two infinitesimal, proper-time-extremizing spacetime steps, calculating the second order variation of the radial coordinate, and showing that it is negative... is something like this possible?